# .htaccess rewriteRule conflict

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am writing a code and build an htaccess file which has the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle page requests
RewriteRule    ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    category.php?cat=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle category requests
RewriteRule    ^author/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    author.php?auth=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle author requests
```

The first rule works fine but the latter seems having conflict with the first rule. Everytime I access a url at http://example.com/category/foobar or http://example.com/author/fooauthor/ I always get a message that the page cant be found because it is still trying to open the index file.

Is there any possibility to get around with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set general rule in the last line:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule    ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    category.php?cat=$1    [NC,L]    
RewriteRule    ^author/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    author.php?auth=$1    [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    index.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

This issue happened because first line support all urls

Comment: Ah, That makes sense. Works like a charm, Thanks bro.

Comment: you are welcome, your up vote can help to others to see correct answer

Comment: cant upvote yet because of my reputation. Will accept your answer in 10 mins as the system allows.