# RewriteRule .htaccess not working multiple

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have changed my .htaccess to make nice url.
What's wrong in this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ article.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ article.php?url=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ category.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ category.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
```

and I got from this
[.htaccess rewriteRule conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990492/htaccess-rewriterule-conflict?rq=1)

I would to make like this

```
localhost/category/bla.html

localhost/seo/bla.html
```

and this is the url in database

```
bla.html
seo/bla-bla.html
```

Comment: what url you are trying to achieve and what is the original url please mention seperatly.

Comment: thank, i have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just just move the bottom part up

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ category.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ category.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ article.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ article.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```